# Android Java compiler opimization

Tags: android

I have code like this:

```
MyLog.d("TAG", "debug string " + aVariable + " more debug string =" + anotherVariable);
```

And MyLog class is like

```
public void d(String tag, String message) {
    private static final boolean DEBUG = true;
    if (DEBUG) {
        Log.d(tag, message);
    }
}
```

My question is if I set DEBUG to false, will android java compiler smartly detect that this line of code

```
MyLog.d("TAG", "debug string " + aVariable + " more debug string =" + anotherVariable);
```

does nothing

and it won't create temporary string objects for "debug string " + aVariable + " more debug string =" + anotherVariable

Comment: A better question is, is this important enough to worry about?  Micro-optimizations are better off left for later (meaning never).

Comment: This related stack overflow question is really relevant but still doesn't have a clear answer to this question stackoverflow.com/questions/8050799

Comment: @Elemental Yep, current question is more "how far will ProGuard go"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing the string concatenation before anything related to the `DEBUG` matters: I doubt that would be optimized out by ProGuard, although the call to `Log.d` *inside* `MyLog.d` would disappear.

If you check the bytecode, it'd be worth reporting back; I'm curious how far ProGuard will follow a call chain to detect dead code. I'd be surprised if the string concatenation went away.

You also can't declare a variable `private` like that inside a method.